# django subquery without using in

Tags: python, mysql, django, subquery

I need to know how to write a django subquery.

I need equal django query for below MySQL query.

```
SELECT main_query.response,
    count(main_query.response) as Total 
FROM 
    Table1 as main_query,
    (SELECT MAX(date_time) AS "created_at" 
     FROM Table1 GROUP BY number 
     HAVING MAX(date_time) = MAX(date_time)
    ) as sub_query 
WHERE sub_query.date_time=main_query.date_time 
GROUP BY main_query.response
```

Kindly let me know..................

Comment: Why would you want do that instead of using `len()`?

Comment: thats my requirement

Comment: Your query gives an error for me because sub_query.date_time (line 9) is not a selected field from the sub_query. What is the query you want to do (described in words)? Something like select the number of different responses that were made at Max(date_time) or so?

Answer (score 0):

It's not currently possible to make Django use a subquery as a "table" source, however you can annotate on a correlated subquery, as of Django 1.11. I think it's possible to rewrite your query in that way, although it may not perform quite as well as a subquery join.